# using parallel processing or multithreading to read multiple csv files more quickly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I've been researching multithreading and parallel processing with python / pandas for a while and can't get my head over the complex tutorials I've run into. My use case seems to be far more simple than what most people use parallel processing or multithreading for, so I can't seem to find a basic, clear answer.

Essentially I have a function that reads .csv files in different folders. These folders can be huge, so I'm trying to find a way to read them in parallel.

So with some pseudocode:

```
def foo():
    for file_name in ["folder1", "folder2", "folder3"]:
        return pd.concat([df of all csv files within folder])
```

I can't get my head around how to speed this process by reading all folder files in parallel. Can anyone ELI5 this for me? Sorry I don't have code to show that I've tried, because I literally haven't been able to make sense of these tutorials, I'm a multithreading newb :(

Comment: Does your computer have a parallel file system, ie one with multiple read/write heads and multiple i/o channels ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes, both my computer as well as the server on which I plan on using multithreading or parallel processing have the capacity to do so